# Access variable inside Jinja2 include

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am including a template in my base template, which the template I render extends.  I set a variable in the direct template and try to use it in the included template.  I would expect the following to output `Active`, but instead there's no output.  Why can `header.html` not see the variable `active`?

**main.py**

```
@app.route("/")
def root():
    return render_template("page.html")
```

**page.html**

```
{% set active = True %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

**header.html**

```
{% if active %}Active{% endif %}
```

Comment: its an open issue: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues/352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug, as set out at https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues/352.

A workaround involves accessing the variable before the include.

**base.html**

```
<!-- {{ active }} -->
{% include "header.html" %}
```